# Update Query in SQL Server via JOINS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables as mentioned below

```
create table #temp(id int, userid int,age int) 

insert into #temp values (1,1,1)
insert into #temp values(2,1,2)
insert into #temp values(3,1,3)

create table #tempMOCK(id int, userid int,age int) 
insert into #tempMOCK values (6,1,7)
insert into #tempMOCK values (7,1,9)
```

I want to  update the first 2 rows of Mock table on #temp table. I am expecting that age of rowids 2 & 3  should become 7 & 9. I'm using this query but somehow it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.age = t2.age
FROM   #temp t1
INNER JOIN #tempMOCK t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid where t1.id in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the user id is the same in all rows, you get the same value for the age.
This can be solved using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), like this:

```
;with cte as 
(
  select id, userid, age, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by id) rn
  FROM #tempMock
)
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.age = t2.age
FROM   #temp t1
INNER JOIN cte t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.id = t2.rn+1;
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbcdc/11)

Answer (score 0):

you can try following query for this:

```
UPDATE #temp1 set age=(Select t2.age from #tempMOCK t2 
where t2.userid=#temp1.userid) where id in (1,2)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this will raise an error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`